# Composer Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout ''

Tags: php, composer-php, magento2

I am running `composer install` to set up Magento 2. Through the process I got the following error:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                   
  Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout '' '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/vendor/solwin/instagram' && cd '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/vend  
  or/solwin/instagram' && git remote add composer '' && git fetch composer             

  fatal: repository '' does not exist
```

I have looked into my **composer.json** file and all I could see is:

```
"require": {
        "solwin/instagram": "dev-master",
```

and

```
"solwin_instagram": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "/var/www/upstream/mirror/solwin/instagram"
        },
```

Do you have an idea why it is throwing this exception and how can I fix it?

EDIt:
I have attached my **composer.json** file and the output from **composer install -vvv**

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.1.5",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
        "solwin_instagram": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "/var/www/upstream/mirror/solwin/instagram"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.5",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "solwin/instagram": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.0.6",
        "sjparkinson/static-review": "~4.1",
        "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "use-include-path": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Composer trace:

```
Exception trace:
 () at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/Git.php:325
 Composer\Util\Git->throwException() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/Git.php:199
 Composer\Util\Git->runCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/GitDownloader.php:83
 Composer\Downloader\GitDownloader->doDownload() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/VcsDownloader.php:90
 Composer\Downloader\VcsDownloader->download() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/DownloadManager.php:213
 Composer\Downloader\DownloadManager->download() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/LibraryInstaller.php:186
 Composer\Installer\LibraryInstaller->installCode() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/LibraryInstaller.php:90
 Composer\Installer\LibraryInstaller->install() at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/vendor/magento/magento-composer-installer/src/MagentoHackathon/Composer/Magento/Installer.php:409
 MagentoHackathon\Composer\Magento\Installer->install() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:173
 Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->install() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:160
 Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:588
 Composer\Installer->doInstall() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:227
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/InstallCommand.php:119
 Composer\Command\InstallCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:242
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:842
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:193
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:251
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:100
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/bin/composer:58
 require() at /usr/local/bin/composer:24

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: Are you following a tutorial? The repo url is missing. Note the `''` after `--no-checkout`, that's where the repo address is supposed to go. The same for the empty string after `git remote add composer`.

Comment: @ishegg Do you think that this is the wrong bit: `"url": "/var/www/upstream/mirror/solwin/instagram"`

Comment: Paste the whole `composer.json` please. Also, the output of `composer install -vvv`. At a quick look it looks a bit weird. Why is the repo URL a folder in your machine? Does that folder even exist?

Comment: @ishegg I have update the response.

Comment: You missed my edit it looks like. Please paste the whole `composer.json`. Also, why is the repo URL a folder in your machine? Does that folder even exist?

Comment: @ishegg I have attached the composer.json as well

Comment: AFAIK this assumes that on your local machine in /var/www/upstream/mirror/solwin/instagram is a git repository, containing a composer.json file. Unfortunately, it seems there is no proper error message.